# Android : Popup certain dialog at first startiup only

Tags: android, dialog, popup

I am trying to develop an app that requires certain values to be set by the users at the app's first startup only, because i don't wanna bother them frequently inputting the values everytime they launch the app. My app has a single activity main and uses certain values that are inputted by the users at first startup. How can I make this possible. 
Please explain me elaborately . :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to keep a track of the first use.

In the `onCreate` Method of your Activity (Startup activity), you could do something like this,

```
SharedPreferences userPrefs = getSharedPreferences("UserPrefs", 0);
Boolean firstUse = userPrefs.getBoolean("firstUse", true);

if(firstUse){

//this implies it is the first use of the app
//also once you are done implementing the logic for first use you need to put firstUse as true
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userPrefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("firstUse", false);
editor.commit();
}
else{
//take the user directly inside the app

}
```

Also, if you plan to save user information in the first use, look at different ways of storing data [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: +1, though change either variable name (firstUse to alreadyUsed) or you condition to if (firstUse) and default to true, as it is right now, you have if (not first use) and then you do stuff as if it's 'first use', do you see the logic?

Comment: It's pointless to keep a `firstUse` boolean in the preferences - you can just check if the values exist in your `SharedPreferecens` - if not, it's obviously the first startup. This way you also check if the data has been corrupted for some reason - imagine that `firstUse` is false, but your other values are missing - you will have a nasty bug!

Comment: I think that check has to be made somewhere in the app ofcourse...but say in the first run, the app shows a getting started guide and then asks user for some data (only one time). Even if the data is missing the second time, the app need not show the guide but if the values are missing, check them separately and prompt them to fill it. In this case, first run variable is useful - first run is tracked and the consequent runs are appropriately handled. Well, I'm just assuming this event..the question doesn't explicitly mention that but yes, it's always a good practice to check the values :)

Comment: what if  I make changes to the AndoridManifest.xml file so as to make the default activity and launcher separate activity... is there any option from this method,,??

Answer (score 0):

show the alert initially and after getting the input values keep it in preference and next time check whether the required values existing or not. If it is already there avoid popup

For getting more information about shared preference check this link **http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html**

Answer (score 0):

```
preferences_statusFirst.getString("boot", "");

        if (status.length() <= 0) 
        {
                showDialog(DIALOG_birth);
                editor_boot.putString("boot", "1");
                editor_boot.commit();
        } 
        else 
        {

        }
    }
```